# Illustrator .ait Swatches into photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, color, swatches

G'day

I need to know the easiest way to import Colour Swatch groups from Illustrator into Photoshop.  (I have only found answers for the reverse in my search, ie PS to AI)

We have an Illustrator template (.ait) that contains all our used swatch groups, which we have no trouble importing into various illustrator files, however I need to import these same swatches into Photoshop. 
We do currently have a work around, but I am sure is the long way.

Q: How is this done quickly?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the .ait file (which is an illustrator *template*) then save the swatch library as an .ase file (Adobe Swatch Exchange) using the menu on the **Swatches Panel**

[image]

The .ase file will open in Photoshop loading the swatch panel.

Note gradients and patterns are *not* .ase compatible and will not transfer from Illustrator to Photoshop regardless of what you do.